# spring boot one to one mapping unidirectional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am confused between how to setup  relation between two entities. I have one entity called equipment which stored all equipment profile. This is independent of everything.

I have another entity called Analytics which should contain equipment. Note that equipment does not depend on analytics. Many analytics can contain the same equipment. That is if a user deletes analytics, nothing should happen to the actual equipment. What I am trying to do is when an analytic object is created I want to store which equipment it references.

My Equipment.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "km_equipment")
public class Equipment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String model;
```

My Analytics.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "km_roi")
public class ROIAnalysis {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)    
    Equipment equip;
```

I am not able to save this relationship correctly. What am I doing wrong? I believe it is still one-to-one relationship because one analytics object can only contain one equipment object.

This is the controller POST API

```
@RequestMapping(value = ControllerConstants.ADD_ROI, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addROI(@RequestBody ROIAnalysis roi) {
...
...
roiDao.save(roi);
...
```

I made a post call where my JSON payload is

```
{
description: "132"
equipment: {id: 5, name: "June 8 equip roi", model: "tst"}
name: "123"
}
```

I dont see any errors. In DB I dont see any column for equipment in analytics table. I was expecting may be the id of equipment would be stored in analytics table because when if I try to get the analytics, I want information of the equipment as well

Comment: Looks okay, any problem you are facing ?

Comment: In the database, I dont see any column for equipment in analytics table. I was expecting may be the id of equipment would be stored in analytics table because when if I try to get the analytics, I want information of the equipment as well

Comment: 1) Show your code: How you create and save these objects. 2) Explain what is the problem exactly - do you see any exception? Or why do you think there is any error?

Comment: @KaranShah Check my answer below; but there is a confusion in your question: you said `Many analytics can contain the same equipment. `; but then defined the relationship as `OneToOne` which seems like a confusion to me.

Comment: You don't see any column becasue you are using `id` as join column

Comment: that is the part where I am confused. Should it be one-to-one or many-to-one. So in analytics, user can add on equipment. User can create many such analytic reports.

Comment: Use new column name like equipment_id in join column

Comment: @KaranShah you need to create a new `ROIAnalysis` entity and find and set the `equipment` field of that new entity to `Equipment` entity with id `5`; which you can fetch from DB and set!

Comment: I changed to @Transient
 @ManyToOne()
 @JsonProperty("equipment")
 Equipment equip; and it started working? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the relationship as `@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)` Why did you define that as `insertable=false, updatable=false`? If you do so; any modification made to the relationship will not be reflected to the database by hibernate. Please remove `insertable = false, updatable = false` part in order the relationship update to be reflected to the database.

Another thing that needs to be fixed is `@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id")`. This is weird; join column should be sth like `equipment_id`!

One more thing is you need to create a new ROIAnalysis entity and find and set the equipment field of that new entity to Equipment entity with id 5; which you can fetch from DB and set in regards to the example you have provided.

Comment: The equipment is already present in DB. It should not be added again nor should it be deleted or updated. Will that work in this case? Or should it be many to one relationship?

Comment: You say `I am not able to save this relationship correctly. ` what does that mean; if that is not updatable/insertable at all; then you cannot save anything to db. that is what I  am saying. also correct the relation as `ManyToOne` if same equipment can be referenced by multiple analytics instances.

Comment: @KaranShah please do as I suggest and remove the `insertable = false, updatable = false`. The equipment entity is in the database; but you need to be able to insert/update values for the corresponding column.

Comment: I did.  @ManyToOne()
 @JoinColumn(name="equip_id", referencedColumnName = "id")    
 Equipment equip;  Now i got new column in analytic table but its NULL